# I can't select my users level from the DB, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, view, controller

im trying to get from my DB, the levels from a users, and print them in a view, but i cant do it.

Controller:

```
public function add_notificacion() {
    $data = array();
    if (!empty($this->input->post('mensaje', TRUE))) {

        if (($this->input->post('id_profesor', TRUE) != 0)) {
            $id_profesor = $this->input->post('id_profesor', TRUE);
            $this->load->model('Profesor_model', 'profesor');
            $json_data = $this->profesor->gets_profesor($id_profesor);
            foreach ($json_data as $fila) {
                $nivel[] = $fila->id_nivel;
            }
        } else {
            $nivel = $this->input->post('niveles', TRUE);
        }
```

View:

```
div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                    <label for="niveles">Niveles</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-14 col-sm-25 col-xs-25">

                    <?php if ($temp == 0) { ?>
                        <input id="todo" name="todo" type="checkbox"> Todos <br>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($nivel)){
                    foreach ($nivel as $fila) {
                        if (in_array($fila->id_nivel, $id_nivel[0])) {
                            ?>
                            <input disabled="disabled" id="nivel" class="che" name="niveles[]" type="checkbox" value="<?= $fila->id_nivel ?>" checked="" onclick="checkAddress(this)" style="cursor:auto;"> <?= $fila->nombre . " " . $fila->seccion ?><br>
                            <div id="repre"> </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
```

Model:

```
function gets_profesor($id_profesor) {
    $result = $this->db->get_where('profesor', array('id_profesor =' => "$id_profesor"));
    return $result->result();
}
```

The form just show me the "Todos" checkbox, but I need to print every "Nivel" user.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my novice code but this might help.

Say if you have a table called "users" and a field called "level" and another called "username".

```
$getlevels = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($getlevels)){
$username = $r['username'];
$level = $r['level'];
echo $username," - ",$level,"<br>";
}
```

That will show each user and their levels afterwards